# MySQL SELECT blocking an INSERT?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, transaction

Is it possible for a  `SELECT` query to block `INSERT` / `ALTER` queries?

I have the following (taken from `ENGINE INNODB STATUS`) on my slave database:

```
---TRANSACTION 26DA7060, not started
mysql tables in use 5, locked 12
MySQL thread id 516232, OS thread handle 0x7fcf8304a700, query id 350388626 event_scheduler Waiting for table metadata lock
ALTER TABLE xxxxxxxxxxxx REORGANIZE PARTITION . . . .

---TRANSACTION 26DA705F, ACTIVE 201692 sec
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x7fc99aa91700, query id 350388642 Waiting for table metadata lock
INSERT INTO xxxxxxxxxxxx VALUES (. . . . . . . . . . . . .)

---TRANSACTION 2499F3C3, ACTIVE 1031443 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 11, locked 0
MySQL thread id 338078, OS thread handle 0x7fcf830dd700, query id 260018270 127.0.0.1 xxxxxxxxxxx Sending data
SELECT . . . .
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 2499F3C4, sees < 2486B035

---TRANSACTION 2499EB0F, ACTIVE 1031500 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 11, locked 0
MySQL thread id 338037, OS thread handle 0x7fcf8307b700, query id 260008885 127.0.0.1 xxxxxxxxxxx Sending data
SELECT . . . .
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 2499EB10, sees < 2486B035

---TRANSACTION 2486B035, ACTIVE 1091724 sec fetching rows
mysql tables in use 11, locked 0
MySQL thread id 330522, OS thread handle 0x7fcf8313f700, query id 255888600 127.0.0.1 xxxxxxxxxxx Sending data
SELECT . . . .
Tr  Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 2486B036, sees < 2486B036
```

They all use the same table. 
The `SELECT`s are identical queries, and have a couple of joins to little used tables.
The `INSERT` is a simple `INSERT` with no joins.
THE `ALTER` is a simple `ALTER TABLE REORGANIZE PARTITION`.

The top one (`ALTER TABLE`) should have started about 48 hours earlier.
The `INSERT` about two minutes before the `ALTER`.

I can understand why the `INSERT` would block the `ALTER`, but can't see why the `SELECT` would block the `INSERT`.
And if it really had been running that long, it should have blocked previous `INSERTs` (we `INSERT` about 250 times a minute on average).

So I'm just trying to figure out what had happenned.

Answer (score 1):

The output is only showing the current query in a transaction.  What else is in the BEGIN...COMMIT?  Or are you running autocommit=0?  Or =1?

`SELECT` grabs shared locks on the rows it is looking at, for the duration of the transaction.

`INSERT` grabs *exclusive* lock(s).  It sounds like the `SELECT` already has a lock that the `INSERT` desires.

Perhaps the `SELECT` involves a table scan?

Note also that it says `table metadata lock`.  This is something 'bigger' than a "row lock".

If you have an 11-table `JOIN` that it taking 12 days, I suspect you are missing an index.  Or perhaps missing an `ON` clause, thereby turning a `INNER JOIN` into a very costly `CROSS JOIN`.  Please provide the `EXPLAIN`, the `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if you would like us to dig deeper into this possibility.

Comment: cheers, `autocommit=1`. It's quite possible the `Select` required a table scan, as it would have needed to look at a large percentage of a large table. My problem is that the `select` was running long before the `insert`. And the `Insert` is simply adding a new line at the end, so surely the `select` wouldn't be aware of the new line (or any of the other hundreds of newlines) that have been added since it started.

Comment: an additional thought, how can the `select` gain a (shared) lock on a row that doesn't yet exist?

Comment: Possibly through "gap" locking.  Sorry, but I don't understand all the details enough to figure out your case.